# React createContext/useContext does not survive between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a shared global state for all components that an app needs, and instead of relying on props drilling or redux, I am trying to achieve that with the React Context.

Why does my user context not survive when I switch between routes? The application bellow illustrates the issue.

Do I need to use any other hook in conjunction with `useContext`?

```
//index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { AuthenticationProvider }  from "./AuthenticationProvider";

const Index = () => {
    return (
      <AuthenticationProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthenticationProvider>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
//App.js
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import { AuthenticationContext } from './AuthenticationProvider';

function AddUser() {

  const [formUser, setFormUser] = useState("");

  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUser(formUser);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Form user: {formUser}.
          <form id="form1" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" id="user" onChange={event => setFormUser(event.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </form>
      <br/>
      Current user: {user}
      <br/>
      <a href="/">Back to home</a>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Home() {

  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        Hello {user}.
        <br/>
        <a href="/add">Add user</a>
    </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/add" component={AddUser} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//AuthenticationProvider.js
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

const DEFAULT_STATE = "";

export const AuthenticationContext = createContext(DEFAULT_STATE);

export const AuthenticationProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(DEFAULT_STATE);

  return (
    <AuthenticationContext.Provider value={[user, setUser]} >
      {children}
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you used a regular `<a>` link to navigate through the app and every time you go from `Home` to `addUser` the app refreshes. To navigate through the app without refreshing the page use the [`Link`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component  from `react-router-dom`

in `Home` and `AddUser` change the `a` links to the `Link` component

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="App">
        Hello {user}.
        <br />
        <Link to="/add">Add user</Link> <-- Changed a to Link
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function AddUser() {

  const [formUser, setFormUser] = useState("");

  const [user, setUser] = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUser(formUser);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Form user: {formUser}.
          <form id="form1" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" id="user" onChange={event => setFormUser(event.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </form>
      <br />
      Current user: {user}
      <br />
      <Link to="/">Back to home</Link> <-- Changed a to Link
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that if the user refreshes the page or tab-clicks on some link that the context is gone? If I am not refreshing the page, isn't it the same as just using the useState hook? In the real app I use react-bootstrap and the NavDropdown.Item component to navigate, what happens in this case?

Comment: If the user refreshes the page the app reset so you will lose any state yes, to navigate to different pages without refreshing the page you have to use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`, if you want to preserve the user state between refreshes you can save it to the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: @Pablo You can use [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap) to wrap bootstrap links with router

Comment: Thanks @Asaf. So, if I understand correctly, the purpose of useContext is to create shared global props that all components can use, as long as that context is still in memory, i.e. no browser refresh?

Comment: @Pablo the purpose of `context` is to give us an easy way to access the captures values through the component tree by passing them through the provider and calling `useContext` from any component that we need them instead of passing as props deeply down to where we need them. The app state will reset when we refresh the page and has nothing to do with `context` but as the state of our app in general. that's why we need to use the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` to prevent refreshing the page and restarting our `React App`

Comment: If we navigate by typing the navigation bar, that too will trigger an app reload and wipe out context, is it? Only way to prevent this is put context in `localStorage`, is it?