# useContext value not updating

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state-management, use-context, react-tsx

I was trying to use useContext to change the authentication state when a user logs in and this would be received in other components to conditionally show based on whether the user has logged in.

Login Context was setup as below

[image: Login Context]

I passed the provider in this way

[image: Provider]

I made a button which upon clicking sets `loggedIn` as `true`

[image: set login]

However, when I re-route to `store`, the value from `useContext` still stays as `false` although I have updated it in the `Login` component

[image: store consloe output]

Upon routing back to "/login" the state from `useContext` still shows `false` rather than `true`

[image: login rerender]

Am I missing something wrt how `useContext` works?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. You dispatch your action, but the resulting state will be visible only on the next render phase. Not immediately. It will not happen synchronously. If you want to inspect that value, you can:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('loggedIn value changed', state.loggedIn)
}, [state.loggedIn])
```

Comment: Yes, but upon routing to "/store", the value from the context is still false though I have set it to true in the Login Component. I have updated my answer to reflect the same. Could you help me out here?

Comment: Can you move the `LoginProvider` above `Switch`?

Comment: @JemyJenesh it did not change, upon routing to `"/store"` the value from the context was still `false`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what was happening from another post: [useContext does not survive between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56608763/14579276)

So, by using `react-router-dom` and `Link` the application now works and passes the context to different pages and components but does not survive upon refresh or on opening a new tab.

[image: answer]

Note that if this feature is required, for example `login/auth`, the best way is through `localStorage`